# Manager Piranha CMS Forms

Tags: .net, piranha-cms

Working with Piranha CMS and am working on custom forms in the Manager area. Leaning how it is put together and get a basic empty page up. I have:

1. Created a menu group and added an item
2. Added the namespace to the webconfig file
3. Created a controller with an action pointing to the view

It worked, but .NET squawked about needing a WebViewPage. On the top of the view I added:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

The page displays correctly now, but I am at loss as to how to create a custom page in the manager section and pass a model to it? I don't have a layout.cshtml, and I can't find a page to attach a model to.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if the view folder has the web.config file, of course!
I checked the web.config earlier but it was one in another folder. Things are working as expected now.

Comment: Well if you have any more specific questions about stuff you'd like to do in the manager interface I'll gladly help out!

Comment: Thanks I am not sure about a few things. When I add another item to the new menu group it does not appear.  I have 2 items in the group, the group shows in NAV but it only links to the first item.  I am not sure how it is supposed to behave.  Also when I create additional custom views in the manager area MVC creates the shared folder and _layout view. Things dont work right then.  the layout view has footers and other defined regions.  Does not appear to be manager area related.  I delete the shared view and it is fine. Thanks for your time!!!